# Downloading a file sent in response to a POST request via nodejs? (no AJAX)

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I have a nodejs server that from time to time submits a post form to an external, third party server that I have no control of - therefore I am unable to perform an AJAX request. I can't use get either.

When I run the code in a browser, the post request results in an automatic download to the default location.

How to download the file to the server filesystem in nodejs?

Current request:
    `$form.submit()`

The form I'm posting:

```
var $form = $('<form/>', {
                      method: 'post', 
                      id: 'myForm', 
                      name: 'myForm', 
                      action: 'example.example'
                      }); 
var csvInput=$('<input/>', {name: 'myValue', value: 'Empty', type: 'hidden'});      
$form.append(csvInput)
$form.append($('<input/>', {name: 'test X', value: '1', type: 'hidden'}));
$form.append($('<input/>', {name: 'test Y', value: '2', type: 'hidden'}));
$form.append($('<input/>', {name: 'test Z', value: '3', type: 'hidden'}));
```

(there are close to 30 more input fields)

## SOLUTION

Solved it by using the `request` function and a key-value array of fd.

```
request({
   method: 'POST',
   uri: 'http://example.com/',
   headers: { 
     host: 'example.com',
     'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
     body: $.param(fd)}
).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('myfile.csv'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using request module, you can just stream result in a file.

```
var formData = {
  myValue: 'Empty',
  testX: '1',
  testY: '2',
  'test Z': '3'
};

request.post('http://example.example', {form: formData}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./myfile.txt'))
```

Comment: I am using this, this is my first nodejs app, let me try

Comment: How do I adapt it from my current `$form.submit()` ?

Comment: You are sure you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request ?
There is no 'submit()' method in it.

Comment: I have it included, and I use it in one place. This is just a normal submit of a form

Comment: You need to set the form data as in my example and change the form url if you want to use request.
It would be easier if you coud post a bit more code.

Comment: I edited my answer to match your form. That's the only thing you need to post a form and save the resulting file in myfile.txt

Comment: I'm having issues getting it to work with names containing spaces :/

Comment: input names can't contain spaces http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

Comment: I'm confident they can, because I'm executing successful requests with spaces in names. In the raw form data they appear as '+'

Comment: This unfortunately does not work... I converted the whole form to your format. It results in an 0KB myfile.csv

Comment: I think it has something to do with how the spaces are passed in the request, I need them to be passed as '+' to work but instead I see %20 or if I type + manually I see %2B